# Can someone explain how houses burn down?

Tags: fire-sprinkler

When I look at houses, all I see is concrete and cement blocks, nothing seems flammable, yet house still burn, why?

Comment: Depends on the region as to what predominant building materials are, but essentially there will be combustible materials in there somewhere.  Most building codes will enforce fire resistance material or fire delaying assemblies.  After X number of hours fire delaying assemblies can be breached and the combustible materials behind them will burn.  Also some materials may become combustible at higher temperatures.  Also interior furnishings, books, cooking supplies provide plenty of combustible material as well.

Comment: Isn't this kind of the same as asking why a fire pits burns when all you can see is a ring of non-combustible stone at a distance?

Comment: Look at a burnt out house. The concrete and blocks will still be there. Everything else was combustible.

Comment: Hard to make roofs / ceilings out of concrete.

Answer (score 3):

Think of all the flammable objects inside and remember that some houses have internal wooden floors.

Comment: You should also include wooden frames, skirting boards, window frames, doors & door frames.

Comment: I think the "flammable objects" covered all flammable materials adequately. Concrete and cement blocks, while inflammable, theirs strength reduce considerably under the extensive heat and long duration of subjecting to such high heat,

Comment: @r13 Caution: "inflammable" is not the opposite of "flammable".

Comment: @DanielHatton And yet unflammable is not a word. It's preposterous. I had to say non-combustible in my comment above because of that.

Answer (score 1):

A house even if built with concrete can act like a fuornace. Fournaces are non-combustible, but if you drop some logs in them they burn very hot and can then heat up and scorch even concrete and soften the  rebars or steel columns and beams causing the ceilings to fall down like pancake, same as  the New York world trade center 9/11.